# Rewrite query string to path

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, regex

I'm having a hard time trying to write regex for redirecting a query string to a path using rewrite rules like so:

```
add_action('init', 'wp_j_url_rewrite');
function wp_j_url_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('(.*)\/jobs\/\?(.*)', '/job/$matches[2]', 'top');
}
```

Essentially I'd want the result to be that a url:
`https://test.com/jobs/?test` would be redirected to `https://test.com/job/test`

I've also tried using `$matches[1]\/job\/$matches[2]` as the second argument of the `add_rewrite_rule` function without any luck. This does work as regex on this example:

https://regex101.com/r/TdmhL4/2

Comment: I've also tried using `$matches[1]\/job\/$matches[2]` as the second argument of the add_rewrite_rule function without any luck.  This does work as regex on this example: https://regex101.com/r/TdmhL4/2/

Comment: have you flushed rewrite rules to regenerate them? Rewrite rules aren't redirects, they're mappings

Comment: Yes I've flushed the rewrite rules as well but still nothing.

Comment: can you install the monkeyman rewrite rules analyser and verify that URL triggers that rule specifically? Install query monitor too and visit that URL and see which rule it says was used. Also that second parameter is not a pure query string, it should look like `index.php?test=` etc, not a pretty permalink. Rewrite rules map pretty URLs on to fugly parameter based ones

Comment: Also, what is at /jobs/? is it a post type archive? A page with a template? If it's a post type archive what's the post types internal name?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm using WP Job Manager plugin and found a solution that works without any code:
By visiting: `https://test.com/jobs/?name=sample-job-title` it automatically goes to the URL: `https://test.com/job/sample-job-title` as I'd hoped.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: The problem with your rule is that you have a mixture of internal and external rewrite syntax. Any rule that doesn't point to `index.php` is interpreted as an external rule, but external rules are parsed by mod_rewrite, not php, so `$matches[2]` won't work in that context.

Comment: having the same problem...